# how to save generated qr code as an image using zxing in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xaml

I have created an application in which QR code is generated by this module. But I have to save it is in gallery.

```
 barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
       {
                 HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                 VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    AutomationId = "zxingbarcodeimageview",
                };


                barcode.BarcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
                barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 300;
                barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 300;
                barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 10;
                barcode.BarcodeValue = "43567890-987654ew567890-";

           getqr.Children.Add(barcode);
              getqrcd.Text = "67890-";
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used ZXing I just saved it as a bitmap with `BarcodeWriter`

a quick example:

```
private void WriteBarcode()
{
    ZXing.BarcodeWriter barcodeWriter = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
    };
    barcodeWriter
        .Write("some string data")
        .Save(@"C:\some path");
}
```